# How to properly change a array of object to another array of object in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How to properly change a array of object to another array of object in TypeScript?

```js
a : [
  {bcdbcd : 1, abcabc : "value1"},
  {bcdbcd : 2, abcabc : "value2"},
  {bcdbcd : 3, abcabc : "value3"}
]

a : [ 
  {label: 1, value: "value1"},
  {label: 2, value: "value2"},
  {label: 3, value: "value3"}
]
```

I want to change the code from top to bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use the input object properties to frame your output.

```js
a = [
  {bcdbcd : 1, abcabc : "value1"},
  {bcdbcd : 2, abcabc : "value2"},
  {bcdbcd : 3, abcabc : "value3"}
];

const response = a.map(({bcdbcd, abcabc}) => ({label: bcdbcd, value: abcabc}));

console.log(response)
```

I have used [object destruction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) functionality and prepared the response object like you mentioned.